# Календарь нужно сделать что бы он сам определял сегодняшнее число

Tags: python

Календарь нужно сделать что бы он сам определял сегодняшнее число.

Подскажите как из этого кода сделать календарь что бы он сам определял день недели?

Именно через модуль calendar.
Сделать не спрашивая сегодняшнего дня. Он сам должен определить какой сегодня день вводим только год и месяц.

```
import calendar

def day():
    year = int(input("Введите год:\n-> "))
    month = int(input("Введите месяц:\n-> "))
    day = int(input("Введите день:\n-> "))
    x = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
    if 0 <= x <= 5:
        print("Сегодня рабочий день!")
    else:
        print("Сегодня выходной!!")
day()
```

Comment: `if 0 <= x < 5:`

Comment: Нужно только через calendar? Нельзя вместе с time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот другой вариант решения:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def day():
    year = int(input("Введите год:\n-> "))
    month = int(input("Введите месяц:\n-> "))
    day = int(input("Введите день:\n-> "))
    date = f'{str(day)}.{str(month)}.{str(year)}'
    workdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y") # вывод, в формате 'день\месяц\год'
    res = calendar.day_abbr[workdate.date().weekday()]
    if res == 'Sat' or res == 'Sun':
        print("Сегодня выходной!!")
    else:
        print("Сегодня рабочий день!") 
day()
```

Вот вариант, где вводится только год и месяц:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def day():
    year = int(input("Введите год:\n-> "))
    month = int(input("Введите месяц:\n-> "))
    date_now = list(map(int, str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')))
    res = calendar.day_abbr[datetime.date(year, month, date_now[2]).weekday()]
    if res == 'Sat' or res == 'Sun':
        print("Сегодня выходной!!")
    else:
        print("Сегодня рабочий день!")
day()
```

Comment: Сделать не спрашивая сегодняшнего дня. Он сам должен определить какой сегодня день вводим только год и месяц.

Comment: Понял, исправлю

Comment: То есть, если вводится только год и месяц, тогда как определить какое число?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать, чтобы программа сама определяла какой сегодня день, а не спрашивала об этом у пользователя. Использовать calendar за основу и любые другие допы. Я сам не понимаю как.

Comment: Стоп, а нужно, чтоб код определял именно текущую дату или только введенную? То есть, например, сегодня 14.08.2021, а у пользователя типо 01.01.2021

Comment: Если текущую дату, тогда легко.

Comment: Текущую мы пишем месяц год он говорит какое число и выходной это или нет. Например сегодня 14.08.2021 мы вводим 2021 -> 08 он пишет дату 14.08.2021 выходной

Comment: Понял, сделаю, сек.

Comment: Добавил новый вариант ниже под старым.